# append file with history line number values

Tags: io-redirection, command-history, output

Is there a way to append `my_computer.sh` with the command on `line 330` by only referencing the line number? or with the fewest keystrokes possible?

```
  326  pip install -U pip
  327  man pip
  328  cat >> ~/my_computer.sh 
  329  pip -V
  330  sudo pip install virtualenv
  331  ls
  332  vi .gitignore 
  333  ll
  334  virtualenv ENV
  335  ll
  336  vi .gitignore 
  337  source bin/activate
  338  cd ENV/
  339  source bin/activate
  340  history
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your shell and the supported features. With bash, e.g., you can type:

```
!330 my_computer.sh
```